# Error when converting python (.py) to executable (.exe) | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

### Introduction

I'm making a project which involve import four files: `gui.py`, `lib.py`, `struct.json` and `ext.json` (main file being `cli.py`).

### Context

My folder structure look like this:

```
root/
ico2.ico
cli.py
gui.py
lib.py
ext.json
struct.json
export/
├─ exe/
├─ py-to-exe.bat
```

I'm using PyInstaller (along with auto-py-to-exe to help me make the actual command) to convert my .py files to .exe files using my script `py-to-exe.bat`:

```bash
rmdir /S /Q exe && mkdir exe && cd exe && pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "../../ico2.ico" --name "Files-Organiser" --add-data "../../ext.json;." --add-data "../../struct.json;." "../../cli.py"
```

### Error

The thing is that I always get

```bash
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './struct.json'
```

when executing the resulting executable...
What is bugging me more is that when I make a folder (and not an unique file like I do here), there's no problem at all (I only changed on parameter that shouldn't have any effect on my code ! )...

---

*Note: this isn't a python related error (I think), since I import them correctly*

```py
struct = open('./struct.json', encoding="utf-8") 
ext = open('./ext.json', encoding="utf-8")
```

*and that it's working perfectly fine when executing the python files*

---

How does this happen and what should I try to resolve this?

Comment: Why are you using `../../`?  I'm not automatically saying that's wrong, but it is certainly suspicious.

Comment: I'm using multiple computers and want this to be as universal as possible since it's a public project. As to why I 'double back', it's because I enter the 'exe' directory, which is at a depth of 2 from the root (where my files are)